# How to transfer a file from one domain to another domain?

Tags: ftp, transfer

How can I transfer large files from `old-domain.com`(old-host) to `new-domain.com`(new-host)? Is it possible to transfer it without downloading the files from my old-host to my local pc? I have an FTP details of both.

Comment: Do you have SSH (Secure shell) access to your new hosting account?

Comment: Yes I do have SSH access.

Comment: @matt i found a solution but it needs my PC on for hours/days.FXP.

Comment: Okay, well see my answer below. It doesn't require your PC to be an intermediary. If it's what you're looking for, be sure to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Matt I dunno how to use it.Actually my aunt ask me a favor If I can transfer her website to my another aunt hosting so that it's she's free from payment.AL I have are cpanel/ftp details.And I never expect that It's a large wordpress site that she maintains since Year.2008.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, [wget](http://www.gnu.org/s/wget/) is the ideal tool for your task. You can tweak it hundreds of ways to download exactly what you need in just the way you need it. You can even download to your new server the entire website with one single command. Wget also has features to efficiently try again if it was unsuccessful or if the file was only partially completely downloaded.

I use wget every time my Internet connection is flaky and I need to download a backup of my website. It has failsafes to get the job done in harsh conditions.

Or, for "special" big files that aren't accessible via a regular URL, you could [establish an actual FTP connection in the shell](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/a/blcmdl1_ftpx.htm) of your new account and have the server directly pull down the big files that way.

Comment: how can i done it?

Comment: @Matt `wget` also handles FTP (including recursively downloading a directory)

Comment: (@ Andy) Good point. I forgot about that. @cloud9 You'll need an SSH client. If you're on Windows, Putty is a good one. Connect to your new server and type "wget fileurl.com/file.zip" or whatever the file is. Now, that's the most basic use of wget. You might want to explore all its features with "man wget".

Comment: @Matt how about if it's an ftp?How can I use ftp by combining get?

Comment: In SSH, type "man wget" then follow the instructions for the FTP options. Don't forget to mark the answer here as accepted, too.

Answer (score 0):

SCP is ideal for this, [SCP Usage Documentation](http://www.garron.me/en/linux/scp-linux-mac-command-windows-copy-files-over-ssh.html):

```
scp source-file [[user@]to-host:][destination-file]
```